# Passar valor de um input para um array de objetos

Tags: jquery, json, array

Estou tentando passar o valor de um *input text* para um array de objetos, via jQuery mas não entendi como inseri-lo no *array*. Tentei usar algo do tipo:

```
var usuario = $('#username').val();
```

E depois adicionar no lugar de *carlos* mas não deu certo.

```
Nome:<input type="text" id="username">
Senha:<input type="password" id="password">

var userstocreate = [{ 
                        username: 'carlos',
                        password : 'Carlos123@'
                    }];
```

Resumindo, eu precisava criar um JSON baseado nos valores dos *input*s, a pessoa preenche os campos e é gerado um *array* de objetos dentro da variável `userstocreate`.

Comment: Pode postar o HTML completo do formulário e o script completo também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var objeto= new Object();
objeto.nome = $('#username').val();
objeto.senha =  $('#password').val();
```

E se precisar criar um JSON é só mandar serializar o objeto.

```
var json =  JSON.stringify(objeto);
```